# failed to build: no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries

Tags: docker, dockerfile, tomcat8

Some output:

```
Step 1/7 : FROM tomcat:8-jre8
8-jre8: Pulling from library/tomcat
ERROR: Service 'myproject' failed to build: no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries
```

Any ideas why the above error? It is wired. I did not have this error before today.

**UPDATE**

`tommcat:8-jre8` is not listed https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/. I changed Dockefile to use `FROM tomcat:8.0-jre8`. now, it is pulling tomcat docker image.

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/issues/109